# Select an element in DOM which is not a sibling, but goes after

Tags: html, css, dom, select, css-selectors

Let us suppose I have the following DOM

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="childNotSibling">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="elementToSelect">
</div>
```

Now I would like to select the div with `elementToSelect` class but only if div with `parent` class has inside it an element with `childNotSibling` class. Is it possible to acomplish this using css?

Comment: Are you asking if you can accomplish this in pure CSS or with the help of Javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately, not with CSS (JavaScript would be required).

Comment: With javascript, it is very easy. CSS, not possible. Perhaps you can use javascript to add a class to elementToSelect, for example add a class named elementSelected, and then use CSS to select .elementSelected

Comment: @tremor, I am interested in pure css. But according to my question the JavaScript works as well. Anyway if you are sure that there is no solution using css I would be glad to see a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSFiddle should do the trick:  https://jsfiddle.net/tremor/f4cghd5x/

Using JQuery here is the Javascript portion of the code.

```
// find all the occurrences of .childNotSibling
$("body").find(".childNotSibling").each(function(index, element) {
  // if .childNotSibling's parent has class "parent"
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("parent")) {
    // and if the parent's next sibling has "elementToSelect"
    if ($(this).parent().next().hasClass("elementToSelect")) {
      // do something with that element
      $(this).parent().next().css("background-color", "red");
    }
  }
});
```